# How do you get your data to show in your browser once using Laravel php blade?

Tags: php, laravel, database, view, laravel-blade

I have my table showing the browser with my information and have it iterating over 17 randomly generated items. However, It iterates over them 17 times in separate chunks. I wish to know how to tell the computer I need each unique item and not 17 of the same thing in chunks.

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>{{config('app.name', 'Inventory')}}</title>

</head>
    <body>
        <h1>Inventory Table</h1>
        <p>This is the inventory table made using PHP Laravel.</p>

       <ul>
           @foreach($inventories as $inventory)
               <li>{{$inventory['id']}} {{$inventory['title']}} {{$inventory['description']}}
               {{$inventory['price']}} {{$inventory['in_stock']}} {{$inventory['on_sale']}}</li>
           @endforeach
       </ul>

       <table>

           @foreach($inventories as $inventory)
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>In stock</th>
                <th>On sale</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>{{$inventory['id']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['title']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['description']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['price']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['in_stock']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['on_sale']}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{$inventory['id']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['title']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['description']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['price']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['in_stock']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['on_sale']}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{$inventory['id']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['title']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['description']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['price']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['in_stock']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['on_sale']}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{$inventory['id']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['title']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['description']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['price']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['in_stock']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['on_sale']}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{$inventory['id']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['title']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['description']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['price']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['in_stock']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['on_sale']}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{$inventory['id']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['title']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['description']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['price']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['in_stock']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['on_sale']}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{$inventory['id']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['title']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['description']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['price']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['in_stock']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['on_sale']}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{$inventory['id']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['title']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['description']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['price']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['in_stock']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['on_sale']}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{$inventory['id']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['title']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['description']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['price']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['in_stock']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['on_sale']}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{$inventory['id']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['title']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['description']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['price']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['in_stock']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['on_sale']}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{$inventory['id']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['title']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['description']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['price']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['in_stock']}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory['on_sale']}}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
           @endforeach
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my code. I have chosen a foreach loop because it iterates over an array, which I have. However, when I just let the first foreach statement it picked one random item generated and showed it in the browser 17 times.
I have then added my second foreach loop that is directly in my table and it does bring up the 17 items but shows in the browser each item 17 times. I wish to show each individual item.

Comment: You don't need 17 rows for each product. Just remove all of the extras, leaving the 1 necessary row. The foreach loop will create the lines for each product for you. Also move the foreach to inside of the body instead of outside of the thead, or that will be duplicated as well.

Comment: Thank you so much guys!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely just want to adjust where you're performing the loop and what content to output. You want the `@foreach` to output `table` `rows` for you rather than the entire `table` structure repeatedly.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>In stock</th>
            <th>On sale</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($inventories as $inventory)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$inventory['id']}}</td>
            <td>{{$inventory['title']}}</td>
            <td>{{$inventory['description']}}</td>
            <td>{{$inventory['price']}}</td>
            <td>{{$inventory['in_stock']}}</td>
            <td>{{$inventory['on_sale']}}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```